# Extract String From Future<String> In Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using flutter, and I'm loading in a locally stored JSON file like so:

```dart
Future<String> loadJson(String file) async {
  final jsonData = await rootBundle.loadString("path/to/$file.json");
  return jsonData;
}
```

The problem is that this returns a `Future<String>` and I'm unable to extract the actual JSON data (as a `String`) from it.

I call `loadJson` in the Widget build method like so:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final data = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;
  final file = data["file"];
  String jsonData = loadJson(file); // The issue is here

  return Scaffold (/* -- Snip -- */);
}
```

How would I go about doing this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how do you call loadJson?

Comment: I've edited my post to include the calling code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadJson` is `Future` and you need to `await` for its result:

```
String jsonData = await loadJson(file);
```

you also can't run `Future` function inside build method, you need to use `FutureBuilder`:

```
return Scaffold (
    body: FutureBuilder<String>(
       future: loadJson(file),
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
         switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
           case ConnectionState.waiting:
               return Text('Loading....');
           default:
             if (snapshot.hasError) {
               return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
             } else {
               String jsonData = snapshot.data ?? "";

               return /* -- Snip -- */;
             },
           
         }
      }
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm calling ```loadJson``` from the build method directly, and so I don't think I can use ```await``` there.

Comment: @FireTheLost check out new update.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting data but not decoding it. You need to decode for using the loaded data.

```
Future<String> loadJson(String file) async {
final jsonData = await rootBundle.loadString("path/to/$file.json");
final data = await jsonDecode(jsonData)
return data;
}
```

Also, please don't forget to import dart convert library to use jsonDecode.

```
import 'dart:convert';
```